# SQLite, identify empty nonnull cells

Tags: sql, sqlite, null

I have some cells that are empty but seemingly non-null (because my IS NOT NULL queries show these cells)

How do I test for them in a query 
`SELECT myId FROM myTable WHERE myId IS EMPTY`

or something to that effect

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SELECT myId FROM myTable WHERE trim(myId) = ''`

Answer (score 2):

There is function: `ifnull(X,Y)`

From [SQL As Understood By SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html)

> The ifnull() function returns a copy of its first non-NULL argument,
>   or NULL if both arguments are NULL. Ifnull() must have exactly 2
>   arguments. The ifnull() function is equivalent to coalesce() with two
>   arguments.